# Word meaning profitable and looking like "ludicrous "

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word meaning profitable and looking like  "ludicrous". I couldn't recall it. Maybe lucri..?

Can you help? or are there some websites for searching look-alike words?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [*lucrative.*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lucrative)